# Google Maps markers not showing up unless page refreshed after initial page load

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When the initial page loads the map is displayed as it's supposed to be, but markers won't show up until page is refreshed once. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
function initMap() {
var school = {lat: 38.901904, lng:  -77.021457};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 17, 
center: school });

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: school, map: map });

var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
return new google.maps.Marker({
position: location,
label: labels[i % labels.length]
});
});

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath:'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
}
  var locations = [
 {lat: 38.901477, lng: -77.020735},
 {lat: 38.901258, lng: -77.021539},
 {lat: 38.903763, lng: -77.018829},
 {lat: 38.900974, lng:  -77.023124}
 ];
```

Comment: Your code didn't work for me at all, because there's a comma missing after `markers` in `new MarkerClusterer(map, markers ...)` Once I added it, the code worked fine, not just after refreshing the page.

Comment: Ha, actually in my original code it's there, but when I was adding it to the form here it must have been deleted. 

The code will work, it's just that the markers won't load on the initial page load. After the page is refreshed they will though.

Comment: You call `locations.map` on line 18 of your code in the `initMap` function.  But you don't define `locations` until after the function.  Is there any danger they're not getting defined prior to `initMap`  being called?

Comment: Also if you comment out the MarkerClusterer, does the problem go away?